# Generalized Derivative:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Denote $d_U,l,f(x)$   as the expression:

$$\lim:  \delta \rightarrow l, U(f(x), \delta )  $$

It's trivial to show that the standard derivative is simply a case of $l = 0$ and $U = \dfrac{f(x + \delta) - f(x)}{\delta}$

Are there other flavors of derivatives yielded by this notation? Can one then create different orders of calculus depending on the type of derivative utilized and create a general theory of Calculuses?

Has this been done before and if so where should I look for more information?

Answer (score 1):

If $l \not=0$, then your *limit* can be evaluated just by plugging in $l$:

$$\lim\limits_{\delta \to l} U(f(x),\delta) = \lim\limits_{\delta \to l} \frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta} = \frac{f(x+l)-f(x)}{l}$$

We **need** the *limit* **only** when $l=0$.

Has this been studied? Well, yes, it's a difference quotient. $U(f(x),l)$ measures the average rate of change moving from $(x,f(x))$ to $(l,f(x+l))$.

**Addendum:** Maybe this is what you're looking for...

What if we consider something like: 
$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h^2)-f(x)}{h}$$

Would this give us an interesting new theory?

Well, no. Here's the idea of why it doesn't:

$f(x+h^2) \approx f(x) + f'(x)h^2 + f''(x)/2 h^4 + \cdots$ so  $(f(x+h^2)-f(x))/h = (f'(x)h^2+f''(x)/2 h^4 + \cdots)/h = f'(x)h + f''(x)/2 h^3 + \cdots$ (whose limit is zero).

In general if you try to cook up some "new" difference quotient, you'll either get something like this above (always zero so very uninteresting) OR you'll get something that's essentially just a regular derivative anyway.

Comment: I guess what i'm asking is have we consider other algebraic expressions (like something crazy such as: $f(x)^{(1 + 1/2f(x + \delta))} - f(x + f(x))$

Comment: Let me rephrase. Are you asking "What sorts of operations/formulas have been applied to functions? Especially those which involve a difference with a shift in the argument and then taking a limit?" Because the answer to that is a lot. You can recast integrals to look like this kind of thing.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_derivative fit into this category

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference is another direction.

Comment: I understand what you mean but those are fractional arguments (And discrete arguments) for the differential operator itself, what if we changed the very definition of the derivative to be some other algebraic limit and generated a new version of calculus altogether from it. I'm wondering if there is a formal study of all these different types of calculuses all put into a single framework

Comment: But what do you mean by changing to "some other algebraic limit"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_calculus is a deformation, but again I sense not quite what you're looking for.

Comment: Here is an example: $\frac{d_{new}y}{d_{new}x}$ = lim $\delta \rightarrow 0$ $\frac{y(x^2 - y(y(x)) + \delta) + y(y(x))}{delta}$ or a trivial example (generalizing the derivative from the coefficient in front of linear terms to the base of an exponential tower: $\frac{d_{exp}y}{d_{exp}x}$ = lim $\delta \rightarrow 0$ $(\frac{f(x\delta)}{f(x)})^{(\frac{1}{\delta})}$

Comment: A valuable piece of information here is noticing that if $a(h)$ and $b(h)$ both go to zero as $h\rightarrow 0$, then $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+a(h))-f(x)}{b(h)} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x +a(h))- f(x)}{a(h)} \times\frac{a(h)}{b(h)}=f'(x)\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{a(h)}{b(h)}$$ but hey, look! That's just a constant times $f'(x)$.